# RenderMapping and clearing Session attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, session-variables

I have a Spring Portlet application and the landing page of an application is a data entry form which is annotated by RenderMapping.

Is there a method that I can override which is executed before the RenderMapping method is called? My requirement is to clear Session attributes using `SessionStatus.setComplete()` and I wanted to do that(if possible) in the first method. When I did that in the RenderMapping method, the Model attributes became empty and when I tried to submit, I got an error which said Model Attribute is empty or something like that.

The reason I wanted to call `SessionAttribute.setComplete()` is to clear all SessionAttributes used, so that I get clear form.

Also is there a way to forward or redirect from one RenderMapping method to another RenderMapping method? Didn't see a way when looked, but still wondering.

Any ideas to handle this?